# Reinforcement learning in Netlogo: Error: No urn specified

Tags: netlogo, reinforcement-learning, agent-based-modeling

I'm totally new to NetLogo, and am trying to create an agent-based reinforcement learning (RL) model. I have recreated a toy model to get help on.

Here, one agent is doing RL by interacting with two agents, one of whom is unreliable (and so interactions with this agent ARE NOT reinforced), and another which is reliable (and so interactions with this agent ARE reinforced).

But I keep getting the error: `Extension exception: No urn specified`
So, clearly, I need to figure out how to specify urns!

The project folder is available for you to checkout at: http://bit.ly/1m8TAxq
Bellow is the minimal, complete, verify code is as follows (though you will need the URN extension in the linked dropbox folder above to do so).

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

```
extensions [ urn ] ;; the urn extension that contains the RL functions

breed [ agents agent ]

globals [ ;; Global variables
  A1 ;; urn-ball name of agent 1 (RED)  
  A2 ;; urn-ball name of agent 2 (GREEN)  
]

agents-own [ ;; Values assigned to each agent
  main-urn ;; Name of the Polya urn used in RL
  interactionPartner ;; Variable tracking who the learner is interacting with
  knowledgeState ;; Variable tracking whether the learner knows the truth after each interaction
]

to setup ;; Setup the stage
  clear-all                
  reset-ticks  
  setup-agents ;; Sets up the agents
end

to have-agents-setup-urns ;; Setting up agent polya urns for reinforcement learning (by observer)
   ask agent 0 [
      set main-urn urn:make-polya-urn initial-weight (list A1 A2) 
      ;; There are two types of balls in the urn: A1, A2 corresponding to the two possible agents with whom the chooser may interact
    ]
end

to setup-agents ;; Setting up the agents in the population (by observer)
  create-agents 3 [
    setxy (-6 * cos ( who * 360 / population-size)) (12 * sin (who * 360 / population-size))
    set shape "circle"
    set size 4
  ]
    ask agent 0 [ ;; This is the agent doing the reinforcement learning (BLUE)
      set color [0 0 255 175]
    ]  
    ask agent 1 [ ;; This is the unreliable agent (RED)
      set knowledgeState 0
      set color [255 0 0 175]
    ]
    ask agent 2 [ ;; This is the reliable agent (GREEN)
      set knowledgeState 1
      set color [0 255 0 175]      
    ]
end

to step ;; The step function
  ask turtles [do-game-play]
  tick
end

to go ;; The go function simply calls step continuously
  step
end

to do-game-play ;; The game play function (by observer)
    ask agent 0 [
      set interactionPartner urn:draw-ball main-urn ;; Draw from the agent urn to figure out with whom to interact.
    if (interactionPartner = A1) [
      set knowledgeState ( 0 ) ;; If the interactionPartner is agent 1 (who is unreliable), then set agent 0 knowledge state to 0.
      ]
    if (interactionPartner = A2) [
      set knowledgeState ( 1 ) ;; If the interactionPartner is agent 2 (who is reliable), then set agent 0 knowledge state to 1, and reinforce.
      urn:reinforce main-urn A2 1
    ]
    ]
end
```

Comment: Did you write this extension?  Where is it located?  See
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/extensions.html

Comment: Following up on Alan's comment: This is really a question about the extension, not NetLogo per se, so in order for anyone to help you, we'd need documentation (or maybe source code) for the urn extension.  Dropbox only contains jar file for the extension, with compiled code--no source.  I would suggest starting by looking at the urn extension documentation, and then notice what line of code is supposedly causing the error.  I did notice one source of error: It looks like `A1` and `A2` never get initialized.  I believe each contains the number zero.

Comment: @Mars Thank you, and Alan. You're right on. This is a custom extension from a colleague, and, unfortunately, they haven't made any documentation for— you're right: A1, A2 never get initialized. Thanks for your help!